# unrecognized selector sent to instance:processing JSON api

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to check if some keys are not present from response of an api and adding it but am getting **unrecognized selector sent to instance** error what am i doing wrong and is the the best solution

```
- (NSArray *) examinationFromArray :(NSArray *) arrayBeforeProcessing {
    NSMutableArray *examinationMutable = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    if (arrayBeforeProcessing) {
        for (NSDictionary *dict in arrayBeforeProcessing) {

            
            NSMutableDictionary *theWholeAudit = [dict objectForKey:@"auditData"];
           NSMutableDictionary *summary = [theWholeAudit objectForKey:@"summary"];


          if([summary objectForKey:@"cases"] == nil || [summary objectForKey:@"percentageOfCases"] == nil || [summary objectForKey:@"fDateValidation"] == nil){
               summary[@"cases"] = 0;
                summary[@"percentageOfCases"] = 0;
                summary[@"fDateValidation"] = false;

            }
            if([theWholeAudit objectForKey:@"duplicate"] == nil){
                theWholeAudit[@"duplicate"] = false;
            }
                        Audit *audits = [self setAttributesFromMap:dict];
            [examinationMutable addObject:audits];
        }
    }
    return [examinationMutable copy];
```

Comment: On which line do you get the error?

Comment: on the summary[@"cases"] = 0;

Comment: Full error message in console? `unrecognized selector sent to instance` should give you what's the real class of the object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\[NSDictionaryI setObject:forKey:\]: unrecognized selector sent to instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58512412/nsdictionaryi-setobjectforkey-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance)

Comment: But I suspect that `[theWholeAudit objectForKey:@"summary"]` is in fact a `NSDictionary`, so you'd have to do instead `NSMutableDictionary *summary = [[theWholeAudit objectForKey:@"summary"] mutaleCopy]`